# Undefined function in a HTML template

Tags: templates, go

I can't pass a custom function to the HTML template with the following syntax/steps:

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("name.tpl")
if err != nil {
    return
}

err = t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"add": add}).Execute(w, nil)
if err != nil {
    return
}

...
...
...

func add(a int8, b int8) int8 {
    return a + b
}
```

Needed function is `add`, there are no errors during the compilation, but while trying to render HTML template I get an error `function "add" not defined`. What am I missing?

P.S. please don't offer other ways of parsing template, with something like `template.New...` and so on. I wish to use THIS syntax.

Comment: What is the reason for not using  template.New?  That is the straightforward way to solve the problem.

Comment: You may wish to use THIS syntax however, parsing the template requires the function used by that template to be already registered. It is your preferred parsing "syntax" that is failing because there is no `add` function yet registered, you're registering it too late.

Comment: `template.ParseFiles` will fail 100 times out of a 100 if the parsed file references a function that hasn't yet been registered. If you want to keep using `template.ParseFiles` then the only option is not to use the `add` function inside the template, if you need `add` *functionality* you can pass an object to `Execute` that implements a method `Add`, methods declared on the passed in value type are evaluated during execution, functions registered with FuncMap during parsing.

Comment: That's bad. So I need to pass the function before the `parse` somehow. Didn't know that. I'll think about that..

Comment: t, err := template .New(““).Funcs(m).ParseFiles(file)

Comment: From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs): "[Funcs()] must be called before the template is parsed"

Comment: @CeriseLimón, it's an invalid code. `name` is required and it can't be empty or random. That's why I dislike this method - I'm forced to write filename twice

Comment: Yes, "" should be replaced by the file name. Is your actual question about how to parse a file without writing the file name twice in the source code?

Comment: @CeriseLimón, well, my code sample solves it, just a custom function is missing if I write the code this way. Also potentially several templ. files can be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function:

```
func parseFiles(funcs template.FuncMap, filenames ...string) (*template.Template, error) {
    return template.New(filepath.Base(filenames[0])).Funcs(funcs).ParseFiles(filenames...)
}
```

Call it like this:

```
t, err := parseFiles(template.FuncMap{"add": add}, "name.tpl")
if err != nil {
    return
}
err = t.Execute(w, nil)
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/exrff18e3bm).